# Espresso test outputs in timeout

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I am doing usual test such as :

```
runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                some_button.performClick();
               onView(withId(R.id.some_other_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

            }
        });
}
```

But the test never ends. 
Now if I take `onView` method and if I put it after the `runTestOnUiThread` statement, then the result is the same. Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not usual what you are doing. You are calling `onView()` on the UI thread of the application under test, that's why the test never ends. It's a plain old deadlock.

To make the test end, do not call Espresso methods in `runTestOnUiThread`. And in UI tests you shouldn't click on `Buttons` by calling the `performClick()` method either. Use Espresso for that:

```
public void test_click(){
    // Click on the `some_button`
    onView(withId(R.id.some_other)).perform(click());

    // Or click on view with the text 'OK`
    onView(withText("OK")).perform(click());

    // Check that a view with R.id.some_other_button is displayed
    onView(withId(R.id.some_other_button)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

The `AppNotIdleException` is thrown when Espresso has to wait too long for the app to become idle. In your case the app is doing something in the background with `AsyncTasks`. Do you have some tasks running?

To reduce time until Espresso fails, you can reduce its timeouts:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    IdlingPolicies.setMasterPolicyTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    IdlingPolicies.setIdlingResourceTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: I know that but, I get this message if I don't use the `Runnable` call, I get this `CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` Btw, my `button` comes from this `alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE))` so that I don't know its id... to call `perform(click())` (but I am googling it right now)

Comment: `CalledFromWrongThreadException` is thrown when you do `performClick()` from the test thread. If you really want to `performClick()` then you have to use `runTestOnUiThread()`, but keep `onView()` out of it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactely what I some minutes ago but I get this `android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click` - At Coordinates: 581, 821 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with text: is "Ok"'.

Comment: sorry here's a critical part of the log `Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 2183 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed ASYNC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED.`

Comment: Do you have `AsyncTasks` running in the app?